# Deleting old templates from CP

Tags: templates, control-panel

How can I delete old templates that no longer exist in my repo from EE cpanel?

I can see you can multi-select and sync, but is there a way of deleting them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

??

```
Your Site -> CP Home -> Design -> Template Manager
```

Can you not access this control panel page? Head over there and click delete on templates you don't want. You may have to FTP into your server and also manually delete templates stored as files.

After you delete things, just run an `add` and `commit` in your repo.

**Edit**

Based on your comment, there are more complex solutions related to repos and deleting files. For example, with `git`, you could use git hooks to guarantee a deletion synchronization between your template database table and the actual templates that are stored as files. But `eeeiik`, that's way too much work for what you're looking to do (I assume).

Comment: OK yeah makes sense. Although would be good to able to just delete templates that were no longer in use, i.e. if 'No File Exists' as opposed to being given the option to sync them back to the repo. Essentially I want the repo to govern which templates are sync'd as the master, rather than the CP.